# Why is my math problems not showing up on screen?

Tags: javascript

I'm having issues displaying the math problems I have created in javascript. I'm not sure if I'm missing something or if I need to take something out. I would appreciate any help or input on this matter it's got me stumped.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Interactive Math Worksheet</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var mathProblem = new Array();
    // writing the problem 10 times

    function writeProblem() {
        var num1 = new Array();
        var num2 = new Array();
        for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
           num1 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1);
           num2 = (Math.floor(Math.random() * 50) + 1);
           document.getElementById("t" + i).innerHTML = num1;
           document.getElementById("b" + i).innerHTML = "+" + num2;
           mathProblem[i] = num1 + num2;
           document.forms["prob" + i]["a" + i].value = "";
        }
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body onload="writeProblem()">
    <table border="0" cellspacing="50" id="frm1" width="800">
        <tr>
            <td width="50">
                <label id="t1"></label><br>
                <label id="b1"></label><br>
                <hr>

                <form name="prob1">
                    <input name="a1" size="3" type="text">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td width="50">
                <label id="t2"></label><br>
                <label id="b2"></label><br>
                <hr>

                <form name="prob2">
                    <input name="a2" size="3" type="text">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td width="50">
                <label id="t3"></label><br>
                <label id="b3"></label><br>
                <hr>

                <form name="prob3">
                    <input name="a3" size="3" type="text">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td width="50">
                <label id="t4"></label><br>
                <label id="b4"></label><br>
                <hr>

                <form name="prob4">
                    <input name="a4" size="3" type="text">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td width="50">
                <label id="t5"></label><br>
                <label id="b5"></label><br>
                <hr>

                <form name="prob5">
                    <input name="a5" size="3" type="text">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <tr>
            <td>
                <label id="t6"></label><br>
                <label id="b6"></label><br>
                <hr>

                <form name="prob6">
                    <input name="a6" size="3" type="text">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td>
                <label id="t7"></label><br>
                <label id="b7"></label><br>
                <hr>

                <form name="prob7">
                    <input name="a7" size="3" type="text">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td>
                <label id="t8"></label><br>
                <label id="b8"></label><br>
                <hr>

                <form name="prob8">
                    <input name="a8" size="3" type="text">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td>
                <label id="t9"></label><br>
                <label id="b9"></label><br>
                <hr>

                <form name="prob9">
                    <input name="a9" size="3" type="text">
                </form>
            </td>

            <td>
                <label id="t10"></label><br>
                <label id="b10"></label><br>
                <hr>

                <form name="prob10">
                    <input name="a10" size="3" type="text">
                </form>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Where are the elements `t0`, `b0`, and `a0`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just check the for loop. I have fix the problem.

```
<!doctype html>
        <html>
        <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <title>Interactive Math Worksheet</title>
        <script type="text/javascript">
        var mathProblem = new Array();
        // writing the problem 10 times
        function writeProblem(){
            var num1 = new Array();
            var num2 = new Array();
            for (var i=1; i<11; i++){
                num1 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+1);
                num2 = (Math.floor(Math.random()*50)+1);
                document.getElementById("t"+i).innerHTML = num1;
                document.getElementById("b"+i).innerHTML = "+" + num2;
                mathProblem[i] = num1 + num2;
                document.forms["prob"+i]["a"+i].value = "";
        }
        }
        </script>
        </head>

        <body onload="writeProblem()">
        <table id="frm1" width="800" border="0" cellspacing="50">

           <tr>

        <td width="50"><label id="t1"></label><br /><label id="b1"></label><br /><hr /><form         name="prob1"><input type="text" size="3" name="a1"></form></td>

        <td width="50"><label id="t2"></label><br /><label id="b2"></label><br /><hr /><form name="prob2"><input type="text" size="3" name="a2"></form></td>

        <td width="50"><label id="t3"></label><br /><label id="b3"></label><br /><hr /><form name="prob3"><input type="text" size="3" name="a3"></form></td>

        <td width="50"><label id="t4"></label><br /><label id="b4"></label><br /><hr /><form name="prob4"><input type="text" size="3" name="a4"></form></td>

        <td width="50"><label id="t5"></label><br /><label id="b5"></label><br /><hr /><form name="prob5"><input type="text" size="3" name="a5"></form></td>

      </tr>

      <tr>

        <td><label id="t6"></label><br /><label id="b6"></label><br /><hr /><form name="prob6"><input type="text" size="3" name="a6"></form></td>

        <td><label id="t7"></label><br /><label id="b7"></label><br /><hr /><form name="prob7"><input type="text" size="3" name="a7"></form></td>

        <td><label id="t8"></label><br /><label id="b8"></label><br /><hr /><form name="prob8"><input type="text" size="3" name="a8"></form></td>

        <td><label id="t9"></label><br /><label id="b9"></label><br /><hr /><form name="prob9"><input type="text" size="3" name="a9"></form></td>

        <td><label id="t10"></label><br /><label id="b10"></label><br /><hr /><form name="prob10"><input type="text" size="3" name="a10"></form></td>

        </tr>

        </table>

         </body>
         </html>
```

Comment: That worked thanks for the help! I knew it was something minor.

Answer (score 1):

I noticed you are starting from `i=0;` and `getElementById("t"+i)` bu there is no element with id `t0`.Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

You ids begin with `t0`/`b0`, so you have to change the index start from 1:

```
 for (var i=1; i<=10; i++){
```

**[The DEMO.](http://jsfiddle.net/7qzhb/)**